# How does this Xcode project on Github link its static files?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I found this project [live555-on-ios](https://github.com/vlider/live555-on-ios) which appear to be using precompiled `.a` files (`libliveMedia.a`, `libBasicUsageEnvironment.a`, etc). But I could not figure out how it gets linked. I would expect they are included in `Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries` in Xcode. But they aren't there. Maybe I haven't kept up with the ways libraries can be linked. How do they get linked?

Comment: Did you have a look at build settings of the app? Maybe, you can find some values under "Header search paths" and "Framework search paths"?

Comment: @FahriAzimov It appears to have nothing interesting there. No bold types. Especially framework search path is empty. But this is an archive file `.a` is that considered framework in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add all required Link Binaries to **Other Linker Flags** in **Target -> Build Settings**.

Use below code in this project to link required Binaries.

FOR

**libUsageEnvironment.a** : `"$(SRCROOT)/live555/UsageEnvironment/libUsageEnvironment.a"`

**libliveMedia.a**: `"$(SRCROOT)/live555/liveMedia/libliveMedia.a"`

**libgroupsock.a**: `"$(SRCROOT)/live555/groupsock/libgroupsock.a"`

**libBasicUsageEnvironment.a**: `"$(SRCROOT)/live555/BasicUsageEnvironment/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a"`

Hope your code will work as per your expectation. Its working ok for me.

Comment: Other linker flags is currently empty. But without touching anything it builds just fine, and it also runs. But it also appear to uses code that is not included in the files pane. Well, I couldn't really be sure. I've yet to test it on some client. I'll take a closer look later.

Comment: I have also downloaded code from given URL in your quest and all binaries are already linked in Other Linker Flag.

Comment: Oh! I clicked on the project instead of the target. How silly of me. But I didn't know you can just put the paths in the other linker flag to build it. I've always use I think Link Binaries With Libraries under Build Phases. Thanks for the information. Any advantages/disadvantages to prefer either one?